# Is there a way to tell which other users have switched to this user?

Tags: command-line, unix, user-accounts, sudo, su

We have a system where we use different system accounts to control different environments. My standard flow looks like this:

```
$ ssh server.example.com
robin@server$ sudo su - env1-controller
env1-controller@server$ deploy
```

However, there may be a number of people doing the same thing, switching to the `env1-controller` user. And there's potential for us stepping on each other's toes by trying to modify the environments at the same time.

Is there any way to check if anyone else is currently using the `env1-controller` user?

Comment: If everyone uses `sudo` you could consider using something along the lines `ps -ax | grep sudo` to see who is currently using `sudo` or `env1-controller` and by running `who` you could get an idea on who is actually running it.

Comment: thanks @Seth, `ps -ax | grep "sudo su - env1-controller"` works perfectly, to get the PID. Could you outline how I could use `who` to then check the user that is running it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If everyone uses sudo you could consider using something along the lines `ps -ax | grep sudo` to see who is currently using `sudo` or `env1-controller` and by running `who` you could get an idea on who is actually running it.

As an example on my machine from my machine the output of `ps -ax | grep sudo` would like this:

```
24324 pts/0    S      0:00 sudo su <user>
```

The first entry is the PID, the second the TTY, third time and last command. If you use `who` you get a list of currently logged in users and which TTY they're using. It could look like this:

```
<user>     pts/0        Nov 23 10:24 (<IP>)
<user>     pts/2        Nov 23 10:25 (<IP>)
```

So through that combination you know that the `sudo` is connect to whatever user is using `pts/0`. This would be the manual way to check.

My guess would be that it's possible to combine that information but my bash skills aren't good enough to just post the answer on how to do that.

The final solution used by the original author of the question was/is:

> I actually ended up using grep to extract the exact TTY numbers, `ps -aux | grep -v grep | grep "sudo su - whoami" | grep -E -o 'pts/[0-9]+' | grep -E -o '[0-9]+'`, and then using `ls -l /dev/pts/${id}` to determine who owned the TTY.

What this does is:

- Use `ps -aux` to get a list of all running processes including some additional information.
- `grep` all lines that don't contain `grep` in order to exclude the grep from the output.
- `grep` the line for all processes that contain `sudo`.
- `grep` the text `pts/<number>` from those lines.
- `grep` just the number.
- Use `ls` to check who's the owner of that TTY.

Using that information you could try to do this (if you wanted to use who):

```
who | grep $(ps -ax | grep -v grep | grep "sudo su - whoami" | grep -E -o 'pts/[0-9]+')
```

But it would only work as long as there is a single result because the output from `$()` would have multiple lines. As you can see I'm skipping the `u` from the `ps` as the added information isn't needed for the basic script to work.

Comment: I actually ended up using grep to extract the exact TTY numbers, `ps -aux | grep -v grep | grep "sudo su - `whoami`" | grep -E -o 'pts/[0-9]+' | grep -E -o '[0-9]+'`, and then using `ls -l /dev/pts/${id}` to determine who owned the TTY.

Comment: Thanks for adding it. I incorporated an explanation of your solution into the answer if you don't mind.

Comment: Ah yeah, good stuff. The reason I am inspecting the contents of `/dev/pts/` rather than looking at the output of `who` is that sometimes the attached TTY isn't actually a direct login session - sometimes it's a `tmux` or `screen` session. In this case, you won't find the TTY in the output of `who`, but there will still be a file in `/dev/pts` belonging to the user who owns the session.